# Converting xml to json does not print xml in same form

Tags: java, json, xml

I'm trying to convert xml to json and I would like to get 1:1 using

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20180813</version>
        </dependency>
```

but the problem is output after converting is not the same form.
Code:

```
JSONObject xmlJSONObj = XML.toJSONObject(TEST_XML_STRING);
            String jsonPrettyPrintString = xmlJSONObj.toString(PRETTY_PRINT_INDENT_FACTOR);
            System.out.println(jsonPrettyPrintString);
```

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--Anagrafica del clienti del mercato-->
<anagrafica>
    <testata>
        <nomemercato id="007">Mercato di test</nomemercato>
        <data>Giovedi 18 dicembre 2003 16.05.29</data>
    </testata>
    <record>
        <codice_cliente>5</codice_cliente>
        <rag_soc>Miami American Cafe</rag_soc>
        <codice_fiscale>IT07654930130</codice_fiscale>
        <indirizzo tipo="casa">Viale Carlo Espinasse 5, Como</indirizzo>
        <num_prodotti>13</num_prodotti>
    </record>
    ...
</anagrafica>
```

and with code I get

```
{"anagrafica": {
    "record": [
        {
            "codice_fiscale": "IT07654930130",
            "rag_soc": "Miami American Cafe",
            "num_prodotti": 13,
            "codice_cliente": 5,
            "indirizzo": {
                "tipo": "casa",
                "content": "Viale Carlo Espinasse 5, Como"
            }
        ....
    ],
    "testata": {
        "data": "Giovedi 18 dicembre 2003 16.05.29",
        "nomemercato": {
            "id": "007",
            "content": "Mercato di test"
        }
    }
}}
```

As you can see `testata` is misplaced with `record`
I mean testata should be first, then record.
Could you tell me how can I fix this? Or what should I use to make it right?

Comment: Why is the order an issue?

Comment: @Pants I would like to have it 1:1 so that anyone can see that is it correctly converted.

Comment: Order of entries in JSON is generally considered insignificant but if you want to generate a specific order then the Saxon JSON serializer has an option saxon:property-order().

Comment: @MichaelKay could you show me how to use it? cannot find it in google

Comment: https://saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!extensions/output-extras/serialization-parameters You can use these serialization parameters either in an XSLT transformation or using a serializer invoked from Java, see https://saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!javadoc/net.sf.saxon.s9api/Serializer

Comment: @MichaelKay ye but I'm trying to convert ANY xml, not this particular and I think solution you proposed refers to this particular case, am I right? Is it possible to maintain proper order in other way?

Comment: The approach Im suggesting is to generate the JSON any way you like, and then use a serializer that reads the JSON and re-outputs it with the fields in a defined order. It won't be the original order, it will be an order you choose.

Comment: @MichaelKay for any XML? Because I think I need xsd or something here

Comment: Order of JSON does not matter though. I don't see the use case in having it in same order. An end user will not be reading JSON and a developer inspecting a JSON response/data should be able to identify it.